# Why is the first match being duplicated in a loop?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two tables called `tableFileTemp2` and `tableFile`. I need a distinct list of computers merging the `path` and `file` columns into `tableFile` tables `path` column...

`tableFileTemp2` //source

```
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
| host  |   path   |  date  | file  |
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
| comp1 | c:\      | xydate | x.exe |
| comp1 | c:\Temp\ | xydate | x.exe |
| comp2 | c:\win\  | xydate | y.exe |
| comp2 | c:\win\  | xydate | z.exe |
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
```

`tableFile` //this is the result, apparently the first path+file is being duplicated for each machine

```
+-------+---------------------------------------------------+--------+------+
| host  |                     path                          |  date  | file |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------+--------+------+
| comp1 | c:\x.exe<br>c:\x.exe<br>c:\Temp\x.exe<br>         | xydate | null |
| comp2 | c:\win\y.exe<br>c:\win\y.exe<br>c:\win\z.exe<br>  | xydate | null |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------+--------+------+
```

`tableFile` //expected result

```
+-------+----------------------------------+--------+------+
| host  |                path              |  date  | file |
+-------+----------------------------------+--------+------+
| comp1 | c:\x.exe<br>c:\Temp\x.exe<br>    | xydate | null |
| comp2 | c:\win\y.exe<br>c:\win\z.exe<br> | xydate | null |
+-------+----------------------------------+--------+------+
```

my code:

```
for (int s = 0; s < tableFileTemp2.Rows.Count; s++)
{
    if (tableFile.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < tableFile.Rows.Count; t++)
        {
            if (string.Equals(tableFile.Rows[t][0].ToString(), tableFileTemp2.Rows[s][0].ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                tableFile.Rows[t][1] = tableFile.Rows[t][1].ToString() + tableFileTemp2.Rows[s][1].ToString() + tableFileTemp2.Rows[s][3].ToString() + "<br>";
                break;
            }
            else if (t == (tableFile.Rows.Count - 1))
            {
                tableFile.Rows.Add(tableFileTemp2.Rows[s][0].ToString(), (tableFileTemp2.Rows[s][1].ToString() + tableFileTemp2.Rows[s][3].ToString() + "<br>"), tableFileTemp2.Rows[s][2], null);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        tableFile.Rows.Add(tableFileTemp2.Rows[s][0].ToString(), (tableFileTemp2.Rows[s][1].ToString() + tableFileTemp2.Rows[s][3].ToString() + "<br>"), tableFileTemp2.Rows[s][2], null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a direct question or explaination of your issue to the title and the database technologies you are using to the body and/or tags. You will get better responses.

Comment: I add the data to the DataTables from csv files, so there is no databese behind. Can you please suggest a question to be the title which describes this?

Comment: This sounds like a `join` operation on two CSV data sets (maybe this could be your title). Which is your initial problem, perhaps try to search for answers to this. It may not be necessary to inject the data into the datatables at all if you have access to the CSV! :)

Comment: I have tried to find a solution already, but to be honest I'm very curious why my above code fails to return the data I expect. So my question is not how can I solve my problem, but why my approach is not working.

Comment: It looks like you are getting lost in nested loop, nested array hell... It's all pretty confusing. But I will try to build a dotnetfiddle that uses your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say in your comment that you still have the original CSV that the data came from. We can do this with LINQ.

```
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
| host  |   path   |  date  | file  |
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
| comp1 | c:\      | xydate | x.exe |
| comp1 | c:\Temp\ | xydate | x.exe |
| comp2 | c:\win\  | xydate | y.exe |
| comp2 | c:\win\  | xydate | z.exe |
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
```

Then the code looks like.

```
var results =
    from thing in
        (from line in tableFileCSV.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
         let row = line.Split(',')
         select new
         {
             Host = row[0],
             Path = row[1] + row[3] + "</br>",
             Date = row[2],
             File = row[3] // <- Are you sure you want this to be null and not the file value?
         })
    group new { thing.Path, thing.Date, thing.File } by new { thing.Host } into g
    select new
    {
        Host = g.Key.Host,
        Path = g.Select(i => i.Path).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b),
        Date = g.Select(i => i.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
        File = "File",
    };

// If you want to get a look at it.
foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", item.Host, item.Path, item.Date, item.File);
}
```

Where the `tableFileCSV` is your original data in a CSV.

This can then be passed into a datatable.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Host"); 
dt.Columns.Add("Path"); 
dt.Columns.Add("Date"); 
dt.Columns.Add("File"); 
foreach (var item in results) 
{   
    dt.Rows.Add(item.Host,item.Path,item.Date,item.File);                 
}
```

Comment: Ohh, unfortunately my tableFileTemp2 dataTable doesn't contain data from the original csv. It is already modified many times. So this would only work if I save the table to a csv and then read it again. But like I said, however I truly appreciate your help, I'm still curious why my code fails.

Comment: This code will work for the original CSV file. Alternatively replace the inner select with your DataTable and access the columns values for the rows rather that the elements by index. This might be better as the columns can be accessed by name. If you have any more questions about my code, just ask.

Comment: How did it go? Did you get any closer to a solution?

Comment: No. Like I said my original CSV contains different data, in a different structure. tableFileTemp2 table is already an output of several previous steps.

Comment: Hmmm, this is hard without seeing your whole code. I would suggest then. Take your initial variables, think of where you want to get to. Do some reading and ask the question again. It helps a lot if you create an example of your problem in http://dotnetfiddle.net/... you never know, maybe using the pseudo REPL there will help you out!

Comment: If this has helped could you mark the answer. It helps you out as people are more likely to answer a question if someone asking has a high accepted rate :) .